# How to get the QML engine of the app in other classes

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm posting here because I'm stuck on a problem with my Qt application. In fact I'm not able to get the engine of the main application in other classes. For the moment, I've tried several method like:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine* engine = qobject_cast<QQmlApplicationEngine*>(qmlEngine(this));
QQmlEngine * engine = qmlEngine(this);
QQmlEngine* engine = QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this)->engine();
```

Why I want this engine is because I need a class to retranslate my app when I want it. For the moment, none of these ideas worked and either they are making the app unable to start nor the app is crashing when calling the function to retranslate (`engine->retranslate()`).

If you have any idea on how could I successfully use the main engine of my app in other classes, I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: In your example code, what type of object is `this`?

Comment: Just solved my problem by getting the engine from my QQuickView object. Thanks.